# How to run a function for every cell based on the index, column name and the cell itself?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
Name    GoogleMinutes FacebookMinutes
Alice   10            2
Bob     15            3
Chuck   40            10
```

I want to run for each cell a function with the signature `func(cell_value,name,site_minutes)`.

In other words. I want to run a function for each index, column name and value.

How can I do it? I tried apply and didn't work.

EDIT:

Non-Working example with the apply:

```
p = PersonDataProvider()
s = SMDataProvider()
df.apply(lambda x: p.get_wealthness(x.index) * s.get_ticket(x.column) * x)
```

EDIT 2: An important disclaimer is that I have an unknown number of columns, inspite of not showing in the example.

Comment: Can you post a working example with the apply?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this works for you:

```
    import pandas as pd


    def main():
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'pete'], 'GoogleMinutes': [10, 15, 40, 4], 'FacebookMinutes': [2, 3, 10, 7]})
    
        for a in range(df.shape[0]):
            cell_value = a
            name = df['Name'][a]
            site_minutes = (df['GoogleMinutes'][a], df['FacebookMinutes'][a])
            func1(cell_value, name, site_minutes)
    
    
    def func1(cell_value, name, site_minutes):
        print(cell_value, name, site_minutes)
        return None
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Typically you could use [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) to apply your function element-wise.

```py
import pandas as pd

# df is your dataframe
# df.applymap(lambda x: func(x))
prepare_dataframe(df, axis=0).applymap(lambda cell: func(*cell))
```

However, your use-case is slightly different. So, you could use the custome function `prepare_dataframe()` to preprocess the dataframe before using `.applymap()` on it.

### Code Implementation - *A detailed example*

The following code-snippet was run on Google Colab and it appears that using `axis=0`, when `number of rows > number of columns`, is faster.

```py
%time prepare_dataframe(df, axis=0).applymap(lambda cell: func(*cell))
# CPU times: user 5.02 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 5.02 ms
# Wall time: 4.77 ms

# Or

%time prepare_dataframe(df, axis=1).applymap(lambda cell: func(*cell))
# CPU times: user 13.5 ms, sys: 1 ms, total: 14.5 ms
# # Wall time: 23 ms
```

**Output**:

```
  |                x   |                y
--------------------------------------------
0 |  Out: (0, 'x', 0)  |  Out: (0, 'y', -5)
1 |  Out: (1, 'x', 1)  |  Out: (1, 'y', -1)
2 |  Out: (2, 'x', 2)  |  Out: (2, 'y', 5)
3 |  Out: (3, 'x', 3)  |  Out: (3, 'y', 13)
4 |  Out: (4, 'x', 4)  |  Out: (4, 'y', 23)
```

### Custom Functions

```py
def prepare_dataframe(df, axis=0):
    # apply along axis = 0 or 1
    # axis = 0 is faster 
    dff = df.copy()
    index = dff.index
    columns = dff.columns
    nrows, ncols = dff.shape
    if axis==1:
        dff = dff.T
        for idx in index:            
            dff[idx] = tuple(zip([idx]*ncols, columns, df.loc[idx].values))
        dff = dff.T
    else:    
        for col in columns:
            dff[col] = tuple(zip(index, [col]*nrows, df[col].values))
    return dff

# This is the dummy cell level function
def func(index=0, column='A', value=0):
    return f'Out: {(index, column, value)}'

func()
# Out: (0, 'A', 0)
```

### Note

In your case, `func()` will be as follows:

```py
p = PersonDataProvider()
s = SMDataProvider()
def func(index=0, column='A', value=0):
    return p.get_wealthness(index) * s.get_ticket(column) * value
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(5)
y = x**2 + 3*x - 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
print(df)

#    x   y
# 0  0  -5
# 1  1  -1
# 2  2   5
# 3  3  13
# 4  4  23
```

### References

- [Documentation - `pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap)

Comment: @lispguy:  Yes, it does not work as-is with .applymap. Your use-case requires some preprocessing. So, I updated the solution. Please check now. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make two simple modifications of your code:

a) specify axis (1, or row)

b) change 'index' to 'name'.

Like this:

```
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck']
vals = [[10,2],[15,3], [40,10]]
col_names = ['GoogleMinutes', 'FacebookMinutes']
tst = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=names, columns=col_names)

tst['result'] = tst.apply(lambda x: ' '.join((x.name, str(x.GoogleMinutes), str(x.FacebookMinutes))) , axis=1)
```